# How can I replace nested for statement with mysql query?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, mybatis

Environment :

- MySQL 5.7.x
- Spring MVC

Table Data (name: TableA)

| seq | level | name | order | parent_seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | name1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | name2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | sub1-1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | sub1-2 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | sub2-1 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | third-2-1 | 1 | 5 |
| 7 | 3 | third-1-1 | 1 | 3 |

Expected Result

| seq | level | name | order | parent_seq | next_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | name1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | sub1-1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | third-1-1 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | sub1-2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | name2 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | sub2-1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | third-2-1 | 1 | 5 | 1 (last default value: 1) |

Now I'm genenrating expected result with nested for statement(JAVA).
Is there any way to generate expected result only with MySQL Query?

The data stacked in random order in the table is sorted by ASC based on the level column, but check the parent_seq column so that it is sorted under the parent data. And if there are multiple data of the same level, sort by ASC based on the sort column value.

Thanks in advance!

++
EmbraceNothingButFuture's answer was great, but the query seems to work on MySQL 8. I'm using MySQL 5.7. Is there any way to use the query on MySQL 5.7?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you're asking for here.  How is the order of the result supposed to be determined?

Comment: Looking at the table above, the data stacked in random order in the table is sorted by ASC based on the level column, but check the parent_seq column so that it is sorted under the parent data. And if there are multiple data of the same level, sort by ASC based on the sort column value.

Comment: OK, I get it.  Yes, I'm pretty sure that can't be done in MySQL 5.7.  Maybe you should upgrade to a later version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:

- Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(name,"[0-9]+\-?[0-9]*")` to extract the numbers and sort the datas using the numbers.
- For MySQL v8 above, you can use `LEAD()` to generate the "next_level" column based on the "level" column
- `COALESCE()` function for the last default value = 1

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, 
    COALESCE(LEAD(t1.level, 1) OVER(ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(name,"[0-9]+\-?[0-9]*")), 1) AS next_level
FROM TableA t1
ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(name,"[0-9]+\-?[0-9]*"), t1.level
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=991661f7c126ec00e883c7fe1a0469e5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm using MySQL 5.7,
How can I use the query on 5.7?